# Training transformer model for summarization task with data generated by translation transformer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, summarization, machine-translation

I am working on a project and this question popped into my mind. Please enlighten me if that is a wrong way of thinking or if it actually might work.

I have a large dataset of text data in language X but a summarization model pretrained for such language does not exist. However, there are models that are trained to do machine translation from language X to language Y that I could use with my dataset. Then, it would be possible to use a summarization model for language Y and translate the output back to X.

Please tell me if there is something wrong with my idea. I am fairly new to NLP.
Thanks

Comment: People do it, but these days you generally want to avoid this approach.

What's the language?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I suspected that's not the approach that would be recommended to take, but if there is no other way I would have to try it and see how it performs :D The language is polish. I know there is a model called pol_bert but it doesn't support summarization task.
Thanks!